# How to loop through nested (two dimensional?) arrays in python

Tags: python, for-loop, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am currently building a bot which grabs user media from a web app, takes the caption from that media, then comments back to its respective post a summary of that caption using chatgpt. However, when grabbing the media from the web app it returns it in a two dimensional (nested?) array. The first dimension of the array contains each post and the second dimension of the array contains the information about the post itself, shown here:

```
[Media (infAboutMedia1, infoAboutMedia2, infoAboutMedia3....), Media (infoAboutMedia1, infoAboutMedia2, infoAboutMedia3....)]
```

The problem I BELIEVE I am having is that my for loop is looping through not just the first dimension of arrays to get the caption, but through every item in every array within the arrays. This is looping the inputs and outputs several times instead of just looping it once per post on each post. It might also just be looping infinitely, but only stops because I set a maximum number of tokens on the chatgpt api.

Here is the code I am using for the loop:

```
# loop through the first 2 media items and post a comment with a Trump-like response to the caption
for item in media[:2]:
    # get the caption text
    caption = item.caption_text if item.caption_text else ''
    print(item)
    print(item.caption_text)
    print(caption)
    # generate a response using the ChatGPT 3.5 Turbo model
    if caption:
        prompt_text = f"{model_prompt} {caption}"
    else:
        prompt_text = model_prompt
    print(prompt_text)
    response = openai.Completion.create(model=model, prompt=prompt_text, temperature=temperature, max_tokens=max_tokens).choices[0].text.strip()
    print(response)
```

And this is what the output is from the print requests:

```
pk='2894873940449854247' id='2894873940449854247_264011168' code='CgsqILaDIMn' taken_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 1, 1, 4, 47, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) media_type=1 product_type='feed' thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/296484960_462095378767406_1748390476667198027_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=irUQpV-zF9YAX85L1kd&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=Mjg5NDg3Mzk0MDQ0OTg1NDI0Nw%3D%3D.2-ccb7-5&oh=00_AfA70njk8gQ1885c7MmgmuPsdrPti5OV1MOdJrBBbz6vZQ&oe=6421AD75&_nc_sid=6136e7', ) location=Location(pk=432035243814359, name='Lima Marina Club', phone='', website='', category='', hours={}, address='Playa Los Yuyos', city='Lima, Peru', zip=None, lng=-77.025541764831, lat=-12.154912018897, external_id=432035243814359, external_id_source='facebook_places') user=UserShort(pk='264011168', username='Edited out', full_name='Edited out', profile_pic_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/286382846_390539753021220_7019031344995736005_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=yx6lC_e87REAX_YK_lS&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCDP2gD2PQP7jTZ1v-TgwhCgaGFYanoUhohuRObCHI85Q&oe=64210E1E&_nc_sid=6136e7', ), profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=False, stories=[]) comment_count=6 comments_disabled=False commenting_disabled_for_viewer=False like_count=94 play_count=0 has_liked=False caption_text='Family bonding time.' accessibility_caption=None usertags=[Usertag(user=UserShort(pk='269994726', username='Edited Out', full_name='Edited Out', profile_pic_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/278686124_398633072077074_6373204507691884000_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=r8wcSim63lYAX9z_DFG&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfD9ad1whAvMSyNnHlQ2Gz2J_2B0AsnEK_5-OVGrjRjH2Q&oe=64223E82&_nc_sid=6136e7', ), profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=True, stories=[]), x=0.7334943394, y=0.4530327101)] sponsor_tags=[] video_url=None view_count=0 video_duration=0.0 title='' resources=[] clips_metadata={}
Family bonding time.
Family bonding time.
You're Donald Trump. Summarize the following caption, in less than 300 words, but do not mention anything about me asking you to do so: Family bonding time.
You're Donald Trump. Summarize the following caption, in less than 300 words, but do not mention anything about me asking you to do so: Family bonding time.

You're Donald Trump. Summarize the following caption, in less than 300 words, but do not mention anything about me asking you to do so: Family bonding time.

(Same thing 29 more times but I had to delete it because my post is marked as spam apparently.)

You're Donald Trump. Summarize the following caption, in less than 300 words, but do not mention anything
pk='2869487531350308146' id='2869487531350308146_264011168' code='CfSd7ThjDUy' taken_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 27, 0, 26, 31, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) media_type=8 product_type='carousel_container' thumbnail_url=None location=Location(pk=299356158, name='Mamacona, Lima, Peru', phone='', website='', category='', hours={}, address='', city='', zip=None, lng=-76.918755, lat=-12.250408, external_id=104699079568997, external_id_source='facebook_places') user=UserShort(pk='264011168', username='constantinothegreat', full_name='Constantino Heredia', profile_pic_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/286382846_390539753021220_7019031344995736005_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=yx6lC_e87REAX_YK_lS&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCDP2gD2PQP7jTZ1v-TgwhCgaGFYanoUhohuRObCHI85Q&oe=64210E1E&_nc_sid=6136e7', ), profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=False, stories=[]) comment_count=4 comments_disabled=False commenting_disabled_for_viewer=False like_count=87 play_count=0 has_liked=False caption_text='Post worthy.' accessibility_caption=None usertags=[Usertag(user=UserShort(pk='269994726', username='alessandrohn', full_name='Alessandro Heredia', profile_pic_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/278686124_398633072077074_6373204507691884000_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=r8wcSim63lYAX9z_DFG&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfD9ad1whAvMSyNnHlQ2Gz2J_2B0AsnEK_5-OVGrjRjH2Q&oe=64223E82&_nc_sid=6136e7', ), profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=True, stories=[]), x=0.4122383007, y=0.2165861268)] sponsor_tags=[] video_url=None view_count=0 video_duration=0.0 title='' resources=[Resource(pk='2869487528112445844', video_url=None, thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/290049480_1174714576705937_1710249698991823676_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_p1080x1080&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=R6REZyJaQ6kAX8Xzaip&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=Mjg2OTQ4NzUyODExMjQ0NTg0NA%3D%3D.2-ccb7-5&oh=00_AfBQscyXmQ0uiCDb9ZmVNsNd_SSFbPqhyfsy6FqBXaZsdA&oe=64228D84&_nc_sid=6136e7', ), media_type=1), Resource(pk='2869487528204754373', video_url=None, thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/290032085_377935577772072_6783237727206669917_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_p1080x1080&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=m3qjHUpobyYAX8Add7p&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=Mjg2OTQ4NzUyODIwNDc1NDM3Mw%3D%3D.2-ccb7-5&oh=00_AfC7YSHjGvYFjmPsWZoqZ7uId5UVQqfR_vMxqybuxJN-Xg&oe=6421ADE4&_nc_sid=6136e7', ), media_type=1)] clips_metadata={}
Post worthy.
Post worthy.
You're Donald Trump. Summarize the following caption, in less than 300 words, but do not mention anything about me asking you to do so: Post worthy.
"I have a dream." 

(same thing approximately 60 more times)

 "I have a dream." "I
```

I believe that the only reason that they end where they do is because I have set a maximum token amount for the chatgpt API, they might actually just go on indefinitely if I didn't have that set.

Please help me I'm going crazy over here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *both* minimal *and* reproducible), with sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it had nothing to do with the loops. It was the OpenAI API engine which was messed up. Changed to another engine - "text-davinci-003" - and it worked.